# Student $t$ distribution table

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, quantile-function

Why is it impossible to find a table of the Student $t$ distribution without the confidence area ?

The normal distribution $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for example, has these two tables :

- $\mathbb P(Z\leq z)$ table of distribution.
- $\mathbb P(|Z|\geq z)=\alpha$ the quantile table

The Student distribution doesn't have a table of the first kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Normal distributions can be linearly transformed to $\mathcal{N}(0,\,1)$, so the CDF depends only on the resulting standard score, typically denoted $z$. The family of Student $t$ distributions has one too many parameters for the same treatment.

You can, however, find differently formatted tables to circumvent this. Instead of using rows and columns to specify different digits in $z$ so as to report the CDF to very high precision, as in the Normal case, we have to use (say) rows for $\nu$ and columns for a $z$-like variable. The usual approach is to linearly transform to a vairiable we call $X$ instead of $Z$, of mean $0$ and variance $\nu/(\nu-2)\ne1$ (hence our avoiding $Z$), so the PDF is $\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac{\nu+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\nu\pi}\Gamma(\tfrac{\nu}{2})}(1+x^2/\nu)^{-(\nu+1)/2}$.

Edit: the examples I've found use columns for CDFs, thus computing in the opposite direction to the one I described above. See also my comment replying to the OP.

Comment: Is there any reference, book, or link to and example of these formatted tables ?

Comment: @Hamdiken I'm [spoiled](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3672.htm) [for choice](https://www.google.com/search?q=student+t+table&tbm=isch), although in many cases you'll see them running in the opposite direction, i.e. allowing you to invert the CDF. (I've acknowledge this in an edit.)